# How to make my custom CSS and Javascript file work in my vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, apollo-client

am working on a project, in my vuejs app, I noticed that if I should navigate to a route with a parameter, my CSS in my index.html and my javascript won't be included, it will give me this error in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

here is my router code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/profile/:id/',
      name: 'Profile',
      secure: true,
      component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "Profile" */ "./components/slots/Users/profile.vue")
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "404" */ "./components/slots/404.vue")
    }    
  ]
});
```

if i should go to the profile route, my css and javascript work but if i should change it to

```
{
  path: '/profile/',
  name: 'Profile',
  secure: true,
  component: () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "Profile" */ "./components/slots/Users/profile.vue")
},
```

my css and my javascript will start working again

here is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CyberSec</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but client doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div> 
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</html>
```

pls how can i solve this issue or what am i doing wrong

Comment: put a `/` in front of all your asset files. `/assets/ico/favicon.ico`, `/assets/css/theme.css` and `/style.css`.